# Problem enabling .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to enable .htaccess files on a Ubuntu server I set up. I changed the sites file from:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    [unnecessary config code omitted]

</VirtualHost>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/document_root
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/document_root>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    [unnecessary config code omitted]

</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I try to view a page in my browser I get a 500 Internal Server Error. Any ideas as to what my problem may be? Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I checked the apache error logs as requested and it appears that the error being logged is:

> [Fri Jul 10 19:39:12 2009] [alert]
>   [client 192.168.1.1]
>   /var/www/document_root/.htaccess:
>   Invalid command 'RewriteEngine',
>   perhaps misspelled or defined by a
>   module not included in the server
>   configuration

Comment: There's probably a syntax error in your .htaccess file. Can you provide the contents of your .htaccess file, and take a look in the ErrorLog (/var/log/apache2/error.log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah... I didn't have mod_rewrite enabled. I feel stupid.

Comment: I always toss a <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> stuff here </IfModule> block around my rewrites.  Now I'm kinda curious... If I were in your shoes would this have significantly delayed me figuring out that rewrite wasn't enabled?